# Controlling accessibility voice over readout of numbers in iOS

Tags: ios, numbers, accessibility, voiceover

I'm trying to get an `accessibilityValue` with a decimal number on a custom `UIView` to readout as "twenty point one", for example, similar to how voice over reads out the duration and keyframe values on the video trimmer when editing a video in the Photos app.

The default setup reads out the value as "twenty dot one". If I set the `accessibilityAttributedLabel` instead using the `accessibilitySpeechPunctuation` key, it reads as "twenty period one".

`view.accessibilityAttributedLabel = NSAttributedString(string: "20.1", attributes: [.accessibilitySpeechPunctuation: true])`

Without resorting to manually building a numeric string to read out, anyone know how to get the number to read saying "point" instead of "dot" or "period"?

Comment: In my view, there's nothing in the OS that can help you as is.  The only way to reach your goal is to replace the '.' by the word 'point' in your accessibility read out.  However, you'll have to check the language before doing that unless you don't internationalize your app.

Comment: That's kinda what I was expecting I was hoping to not have to go down the rabbit hole of translations and localizations for "point". Just seems kind of odd that there isn't better voice over support for numeric values, if that's the case ‍♂️

Comment: @XLE_22 I just discovered by accident that a string generated from a  `ByteCountFormatter` reads out as "twenty point one megabytes", for example. Playing around with `NumberFormatter` to see if I can get it working there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it! Formatting a number using a `NumberFormatter` with a style of `.spellOut` will generate a string with the fully spelled out value. Not what we want for a label's text, but exactly what we want for an accessibility label.

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut

let label = UILabel()
label.text = formatter.string(from: 20.1)
label.accessibilityLabel = formatter.string(from: 20.1)

// prints out "twenty point one"
print(label.accessibilityLabel)
```